# Closed form for Numbers in a Triangular Array

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I have a particular triangular array

$$
\begin{matrix}
1 &  \\
1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 3 & 9 & 15\\
1 & 4 & 18 & 60 & 105\\
1 & 5 & 30 & 150 & 525 & 945\\
\end{matrix}
$$
The $T(i,j)$th entry is found by the following recursive formula:

$$(2k+1)T(n,k)+T(n,k+1)=T(n+1,k+1)$$

To read, $T(2,1)=2$.  Here I am taking $n$ as the row and $k$ as the column.  The first entry is the "$0$"th row and "$0$"th column.  Also note that $T(n,k)=0$ if $n<k$

I tried looking on the OEIS website for combinations of these numbers and didn't have much success.  What would be a method for finding a closed form for this type of recursive triangle?  I know that the number $T(n,n)=(2n-1)!!$ where $n!!$ is the (in this case odd) double factorial with the trivial case $T(0,0)=1$

Has anyone ever seen this particular triangle or know of any particular sequences of numbers found here?

EDIT:

As per Ross Milikan's suggestion, looking at the number 60.  60 can be obtained by multiplying 5 and 9 because $T(3,2)=9$ and $=2\cdot 2+1$.  Then add $45$ and $15$, since $T(3,3)=15$.  Thus, $$60 = T(4,3) = (2\cdot 2+1)T(3,2)+T(3,3)=5\cdot 9+15$$

Comment: @RossMillikan, i have made the corrections.  The formula should have been $2k+1$ not $2n+1$, where $n$ is the row starting from 0 and $k$ is the column starting from 0.  Then $60=(2\cdot 2+1)9+15$.  Sorry

Comment: Thanks.  I would suggest you edit the example into the question.  I was now able to reproduce the table in Excel.

Comment: Have you tried generating functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was staring at the problem last night and I got inspired.  Using Pascal's Triangle,

$$
\begin{matrix}
1 \\
1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 3 & 3 & 1 \\
1 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 1\\
1 & 5 & 10 & 10 & 5 & 1\\
\end{matrix}
$$

Looking at column 2, for example we have $(3,9,18,30,...)$.  Taking out a $3$ yields $(1,3,6,10,...)$ or the 2nd column of Pascal's Triangle.

Looking at column 3 we have $(15, 60, 150, 300,...)$.  Taking out a $15$ yields $(1,4,10,20,...)$ or the third column of Pascal's Triangle.

So looking back at the triangle generated by the above recursion,
$$(2k+1)T(n,k)+T(n,k+1)=T(n+1,k+1)$$
it appeared that if we multiplied the $T(n,n)=(2n-1)!!$ by the appropriate entry from Pascal's we achieve success.  Thus

$$T(n,k)=\binom{n}{k}(2k-1)!!$$

By plugging in this to the LHS we get 
$$(2k+1)\binom{n}{k}(2k-1)!!+\binom{n}{k+1}[2(k+1)-1]!!$$
$$=\binom{n}{k}(2k+1)!!+\binom{n}{k+1}(2k+1)!!$$
$$=\left[\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k+1}\right](2k+1)!!$$
$$=\binom{n+1}{k+1}(2k+1)!!$$
$$=T(n+1,k+1)$$